# How to repair a bad manipulation?

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

I've just posted a comment about the following question: [$P(X)$ is locally compact if $X$ is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506517/px-is-locally-compact-if-x-is/507267#507267)

Unfortunately, I forgot a "dollar" somewhere, and the comment is unreadable. Moreover, this caused some perturbations on the whole series of comments and, what is worse, I'm now completely unable to physically click on the "edit" button. Most likely, this is due to my own computer.

Could anybody help me for that; for example, by simply destroying the comment if he/she is able to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be similar problem like [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10487/comment-trouble) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long).

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be best to flag the comment, stating that something went wrong with your comment.  A moderator can then edit your comment to try to fix it up (as I am about to do).

---

I think it's fixed now.  (And it was an *extra* `$` as opposed to a missing one.)

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Your problems with editing could be due to the choice of browser (if this is a problem you're experiencing regularly).

An example:
I'm using Firefox and Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04. On stackexchange, I often have problems editing and answering with Firefox, where as I had never had problems using Chrome.

Comment: The problem was just a typo that caused the MathJax rendering to go awry.  (It was interpreting some math as plain text, and some plain text as math.)

Comment: I'm using "Safari", with MacOsX.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I understand, and I see you fixed that problem. But I don't think that should have anything to do with the ability to edit, right?

Comment: @Etienne I haven't used Safari for a while (so I haven't seen this behaviour), but as a general recommendation I would try different browsers when encountering problems like the one you described.

Comment: I'll follow your advise; thanks!

Comment: @Lisa A mistake in MathJax can indeed render some comments too long, which can cause that the edit button is not available. (For example, you can see in [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/#comment22353_4479) in formatting sandbox that the date is not visible. (Which is the place where the poster can click on delete, or - for a few minutes after posting - on edit.) Some workaround is explained in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2818/) by Willie Wong.

Comment: Oh ok, that's good to know!